# Visual Basic - How do I assign values to SelectedIndex items in a drop-down list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspxcombobox

I've hit an obstacle. I just want to learn how I can assign SelectedIndex items with the declared costs? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

I have declared the costs of the taco types but I am not sure how I can assign them to the SelectedIndex items for the `ddlTacoType` in Visual Basic. Is it a good idea to use a switch statement? Ideally, the output should display the cost as 8.99 when the user selects "Chipotle Chicken."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Richard

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqVy6.png)

```
' Project:  Street Tacos Order Form
' Author:   Richard Lew
' Date:     November 3, 2019
' Purpose:  The web application allows a customer to fill out a street taco order form.

Public Class About
    Inherits Page
    Private _decChicken As Decimal = 8.99
    Private _decPork As Decimal = 9.99
    Private _strFish As Decimal = 12.99
    Private _strBeef As Decimal = 13.99
    Private _strExtra As Decimal = 0.99
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        ' The btnSubmit click event will calculate the cost of the street tacos
        ' based on the type of tacos selected.

        ' Declare and initialize variables
        Dim decTacoCost As Decimal
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
        Dim decChickenCost As Decimal = 8.99D
        Dim decPorkCost As Decimal = 9.99D
        Dim decFishCost As Decimal = 12.99D
        Dim decBeefCost As Decimal = 13.99D
        Dim decExtraCost As Decimal = 0.99
        Dim strName As String
        Dim strAddress As String
        Dim strPhone As String
        Dim decOrderCost As Decimal = 0D
        Dim strMessage As String

        ' Trim additional spaces that are entered by the user
        strName = txtName.Text.Trim
        strAddress = txtAddress.Text.Trim
        strPhone = txtPhone.Text.Trim

        ' Clear the Order Message
        lblOrder.Text = ""

        ' Ensure a Taco Selection is Selected
        If ddlTacoType.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
            lblTacoTypeError.Visible = True
        Else
            lblTacoTypeError.Visible = False
        End If
        ' Ensure a Topping is Selected
        If Not (chkRedChili.Checked Or chkGreenChili.Checked Or chkBeans.Checked Or chkCream.Checked Or chkLime.Checked Or chkNoToppings.Checked) Then
            lblToppingsError.Visible = True
        Else
            lblToppingsError.Visible = False
        End If

        ' Calculate the cost of the Taco(s) selected by the user
        Select Case decTotalCost
            Case 0
                decTacoCost = decChickenCost
            Case 1
                decTacoCost = decPorkCost
            Case 2
                decTacoCost = decFishCost
            Case 3
                decTacoCost = decBeefCost
            Case 4
                decTacoCost = decExtraCost
        End Select



    End Sub
End Class
```

When the user selects a taco type in the `ddlTacoType` drop-down list, the program should associate the item with its cost and calculate the total cost of the selected item at the end of the program.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: That code was written 3 days in the future! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your logic in selected index change event of dropdown

```
Protected Sub onSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlTacoType.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```